# r xml merging lists elements works oustide function, returns error when inside function

Tags: xml, r, list, function, merge

I am `R` newbie. In `R` I'm trying to extract some data from various levels of `XML node` and put it into one data frame.

The code I came up with is something like this:

```
src <- sapply(node[[1]][1:5], function(x)  # extract data from first 5 sub-sub-nodes of 1st sub-node (example)
 {

      names <- xpathSApply(x, "choice", xmlGetAttr, "name") # return list of vectors
      ids <- xpathSApply(x, "choice", xmlGetAttr, "id") # return list of vectors
      names2 <- xpathSApply(x, ".", xmlGetAttr, "name") # return list of vectors

      # merge lists together
      final_list <- mapply(rbind, names, ids, names2)

      # merge elements of final_list into data frame
      df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, final_list)
      # -> returns error, doesn't work!!



   }       
          )

df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, src)  
# works fine outside function
```

Thing is, the code returns an error:

Error in do.call(cbind.data.frame, final_list) : 
 second argument must be a list

.. when `do.call` is put INSIDE function. However, it works just fine when `do.call` is applied to src function result outside the function. The class of src function output is "list" (list of matrices). As far as I'm concerned "mapply" should return a list. I am puzzled.

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

the xml i am parsing looks like this:

```
<a name="node" >
<b>
 <c name="subnode1" >
  <choice name="1" id="125096778" />
  <choice name="2" id="125096782" />
  <choice name="3" id="125096786" />
 </c>

 <c name="subnode2" >
  <choice name="1" id="125097062" />
  <choice name="2" id="125097083" />
  <choice name="3" id="125096990" />
  <choice name="4" id="125097065" />
  <choice name="5" id="125096984" />
</c>

 <c name="subnode3” >
  <choice name="1" id="125097219" />
  <choice name="2" id="125097227" />
  <choice name="3" id="125097231" />
  <choice name="4" id="125097235" />
  <choice name="5" id="125097243" />
  <choice name="6" id="125097215" />
  <choice name="7" id="125097239" />
  <choice name="8" id="125097223" />
  <choice name="9" id="125097247" />
 </c>

 <c name="subnode4" >
  <choice name="1" id="125097251" />
  <choice name="2" id="125097259" />
  <choice name="3" id="125097255" />
 </c>

 <c name="subnode5" >
  <choice name="1" id="125097303" />
  <choice name="2" id="125097306" />
  <choice name="3" id="125097309" />
 </c>
</b>
</a>
```

Comment: `mapply` always simplifies so it is unlikely it will produce a list as output. You can try `Map` instead which will not simplify. Without a reproducible example it is hard to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: added xml code to provide reproducible example